# DISCORD JS Some commands work some don't, no errors given

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So my bot was running fine until I tried to host it on heroku. After I hosted it, some of the commands wouldn't work and it would be completely random. I even tried copying and pasting a command that does work and replacing the words to change the content of the command, and it wouldn't work. Below I'll post an example of a working command and a non working command, any help would be appreciated as I am very confused because I am receiving no errors

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    var hiresponse = helloResponse [Math.floor(Math.random()*helloResponse .length)];
    if (msg.includes("hey")||msg.includes("hi")) {
        message.channel.startTyping();
        setTimeout(()=>{
            message.channel.send(hiresponse).then((message)=>{
                message.channel.stopTyping();
            });
        }, 5000)
    }
//Working command

    if (message.channel.type == "dm") return;
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    var gmresponse = goodmorningResponse [Math.floor(Math.random()*goodmorningResponse .length)];
    if (msg.includes("goodmorning")||msg.includes("good morning")) {
        message.channel.startTyping();
        setTimeout(()=>{
            message.channel.send(gmresponse).then((message)=>{
                message.channel.stopTyping();
            });
        }, 7000)
    }
//Non working command
```

Comment: You need to provide the error you're getting

Comment: as i said in the post, im getting no errors

Comment: Could you please show what `helloResponse` and `goodmorningResponse` are? That's the only difference that I can see that should matter.

Comment: Hi! they're just arrays. const helloResponse = [ "Test", "Test 2" ] const goodmorningResponse = ["Test 3", "Test 4"]